# When can we expect upgrade of 13" macbook pro?

Tags: macbook-pro, hardware

Core2Duo is old architecture in comparison with iCore (MacBook Pro 15" and 17").

When can we expect upgrade of 13" macbook pro?

And any rumors about what we can expect?

---

**Apple Updates MacBook Pro with Next Generation Processors, Graphics & Thunderbolt I/O Technology**
http://www.apple.com/pr/library/2011/02/24mbp.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MacRumors [expects a new MacBook Pro soon](http://buyersguide.macrumors.com/#MacBook_Pro) (this April, probably). It will use Intel's new Sandy Bridge architectures.